# Compare two files with input from third file and write the biggest count to the fourth file

Tags: python

I have three files:

file:1

```
mango
banana
orange
```

file:2 -> the count is in string, because when I wrote to file:2 -> write() only let me write strings.

```
mango 2
banana 3
```

file:3 -> the count is in string, because when I wrote to file:3 -> write() only let me write strings.

```
banana 4
orange 3
```

I want to take file:1 and check with file:2 & file:3. If they are present, I want to take the entry with the biggest count and write to file:4.

Expected output in file:4

```
mango 2
banana 4
orange 3
```

I tried writing file:2 and file:3 to a dictionary and do a dictionary compare, but I am getting lost with two many open() files.
I am new to python. Not being able to write an integer to file with write() itself threw me off.
Appreciate your help/hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for as many files as you want for input.

```
values = {}
def func(file):
    number_of_lines = file.readlines()
    for line in number_of_lines:
        elements = line.split()
        if (elements[0] in values):
            if (int(elements[1]) > int(values[elements[0]])):
                values[elements[0]] = elements[1]
        else:
            values[elements[0]] = 0
    file.close()


f = open("1.txt", "r")
func(f)
f = open("2.txt", "r")
func(f)
f = open("3.txt", "r")
func(f)
f = open("4.txt", "w+")
for key, val in values.items():
    print (key, " ", val)
    to_write = key + " " + val + "\n"
    f.write(to_write)

f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you. Works well. Appreciate the help. Helps me dive right in.

Answer (score 1):

Following produces file4 from file1, file2, file3;

```
def load_file(filepath):
  " Loads the files as dictionary "
  with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
    return dict(line.rstrip().split() for line in f)

# Get keys
with open('file1.txt') as file1:
  keys = [line.rstrip() for line in file1]

# Produce output (file4)
with open('file4.txt', 'w') as file_out:
  dic1 = load_file('file2.txt')
  dic2 = load_file('file3.txt')

  for k in keys:
    v1 = int(dic1.get(k, 0))  # convert dic counts to int)
    v2 = int(dic2.get(k, 0))  # (use default to 0 if not present)
    v = max(v1, v2)
    if v > 0:                 # only write if count > 0
        file_out.write(f"{k} {v}\n")
```